# Uploading file on Step in Bonita

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, contract, multiple-file-upload, bonita

i would like to upload and download a file. I know the FileUploadDownload Example but i required to upload document on step not on instantiation form.how can i achieve that i have made contract on step and assigned it to document variable initialized at pool level, but its not working. it gives error that "Error submitting form". I am new to bonita help anybody.

Steps for process building are given as follows:
Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

Step 3:
[image]

Step 4:
[image]

Error:
When i submit form Error generates which is given as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your issue, you need to remove the contract inputs on the process instantiation, change the default value for the document variables and remove the process instantiation form:

1. Remove contract inputs

   - Select the pool.
   - Go to Execution -> Contract.
   - Remove the file inputs.
2. Document variables default value

   - Select the pool
   - Go to Data -> Documents
   - For each variable, Edit -> Select None in Initial content
3. Process instantiation form

   - Select the pool
   - Go to Execution -> Instantiation form
   - Remove the current Target form

That should do the trick :)

Also, check the new version of the file upload example, I removed the limitation that duplicate the document each time the steps is submit:
https://github.com/Bonitasoft-Community/file-upload-download-example

Cheers